# Remove Toolbar from product list grid mode

Tags: magento-1.9

For showing product in my newsletter i am using below code .I created a new newsletterproductlist.phtml file and remove unwanted filters ....it is working fine but only showing 12 products i just want to show all products in particular category i tried to add `product_count="20",  hide_toolbar="1"`  but it is now showing any effect so please guide me the right direction to show all products.

`{{block type="catalog/product_list"  column_count="4" category_id="9"  template="catalog/product/newsletterproductlist.phtml"}}`

I remove toolbar from the new listing page i created as i don't want to show any type of filter in my newsletter so guys is there any option to show all products in category?

Comment: Your question is not clear. please elaborate.

Comment: I edit my question please check

Answer (score 1):

in your phtml file comment below code that will remove toolbar

```
<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
```

Comment: Hi alreay did the pagination is not showing but still showing only 12 products